# Hibernate JPA OneToOne Relationship with a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I'd like to create a OneToOne relation between two entities(also tables in mysql). When i get a post request i want to save the A entity and then B entity is saved automatically, because there is a column in B ("a_id") that is foreign key of the primary key in A ("id_a"). How can i map them correctyl?

```
@Table("a_tb")
public class A(){
    @Column(name="id_a")
    private Long idA;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "aId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
    private B b;
}
@Table("b_tb")
public class B(){
    @Column(name="id_b")
    private Long idB;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private Long aId;
}
```

Have tried to set idA to A type, but when i call the get method he will loop calling A with B innested that as A innested and so on..
I just want to save the id of A in B, not the entire object, otherwise he will return the entire object when i call the get method and the loop is back.
The mapping is correct, not the autoset of the value in a_id in B.

What I expect is: when i create A, B gets **automatically** the id of A and save it to its column ("id_a") in db when i request to save object A. That's should work with delete too (when i delete A, B is deleted too).
The matched JSON will be:

```
{
 "a":{
      "id_a": "value",
     },
 "b":{
      "id_b": "value",
      "a_id": "id_a"
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: *otherwise he will return the entire object when i call the get method.* that depends. Hibernate might return proxy with only ID attached, not actual object. Eg if you would get lazy loaded @OneToOne relation object and call getThatObject().getId() it would not load that lazy relation and Id would be returned as requested. I don't think that trying to outsmart Hibernate on how to use it is good idea. The same applies for eg ids that you want to set. You create Object, set id and set the relation or even you can use plan Reference if you are using EntityManager directly.

Answer (score 0):

from the first look it looks like

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idA_id")
A a;
```

would be the change you need and

Comment: Updated the question, what you said will return the entire object A, not just the id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide one to one mapping [Reference] in both the classes.
   If parent reference, not setup automatically you can create a transient variable and set parent's primary key using it.

Try this Example:

```
@Table("a_tb")
    public class A(){
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "aId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
        private B b;
    }

    @Table("b_tb")
    public class B(){
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
        private A a;

        @Transient
        private Long aId;

        // getters and setters

        public void setAId(Long aId){
            if(aId != null){ 
               this.a = new A();
               this.a.setId(aId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is, but i'd like to avoid to call a set method.. hibernate should do this without any manual set